# Why was Quicksilver vulnerable to Scarlet Witch's curse in the Decimation comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, quicksilver

**Spoiler from Uncanny Avengers #4!**

In the [Decimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(comics)) story arc, the overwhelming majority of mutants lost their powers due to the magic done by Scarlet Witch. This evidently included Quicksilver (Pietro Maximoff), her own brother.

But how he did he lose his power when the latest retcon reveals that [he isn't actually a mutant](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/02/26/quicksilver-and-scarlet-witchs-new-comic-book-origin-revealed)?
[image]

Why was Quicksilver affected when other non-mutants weren't? Spider-Man and the Inhumans retained their powers, so why not Quicksilver?

Comment: Hmm. Fair enough. Their powers still seem to be x-gene based though.

Comment: Good point. I've taken the liberty of making the retcon a bit clearer since that's definitely the key point of the question.

Comment: Changed title should scare off anyone stupid enough to read ahead :-)

Comment: @Richard But Decimation comics is too old and the person who clicks on the question might be unaware with new retcon, anyways first line can stop him from reading froward in that case ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now, my understanding is that no explanation has been given. However, there are some possibilities:

- **It's psychomatic** - Quicksilver believed himself to be a mutant and, when he learned that mutants had been depowered, he effectively blocked off his powers. They're still there, but he's convinced he can't use them. I believe that he was depicted as not having his powers before he learned of M-Day, so this seems unlikely.
- **Wanda specifically included him** - More likely in my mind, Wanda, originator of the effect, included Quicksilver when she depowered the mutants since, in her mind, he was a mutant and, as someone close to her, he'd be likely to be included as a specific case.
- **What the High Evolutionary did involves the X-gene** - It's possible that whatever tweaking was done still involves the X-gene such that the blanket shutdown of it affected Quicksilver's powers despite him not technically being a mutant. Since I believe Quicksilver has been detected as mutant in issues past, that seems to support the idea that some part of his powers works in a similar manner despite him not actually being a mutant.
- **Sloppy writing** - Sadly, this seems like the most likely case to me.

Comment: Point 3 seems most likely in-universe, point 4 seems most likely period.

Comment: Point #2 is a strong point as well. Wanda's powers have varied somewhat over the course of time. Sometimes (especially in her early days) she has been able to cause random improbable events, where *she* doesn't know exactly what to expect; more recently, she's had much more control. Her belief that Pietro was a mutant might readily be sufficient to include him, even if she was mistaken. Also, one suspects that, in the fullness of time, they'll both be considered mutants again.

Comment: @RDFozz: c.f. Point #4. :-D